# Is it safe to skip the initial block verification at startup?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, database, bitcoin.conf

The longest step in bitcoin core initialization is "Verifying last 6 blocks at level 3". The number of blocks checked at startup [went down from 288](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24641/what-is-verifying-last-288-blocks-at-level-3) in 2014 to 6 now. Therefore, in order to speedup bitcoin core initialization I am thinking about lowering this number further to 2-3 with the `checkblocks` option.

However, I wonder how risky this is? In case bitcoin core shuts down incorrectly, isn't it unlikely that all the last 6 blocks become corrupted? Isn't 2-3 blocks enough?

Comment: I think Bitcoin Core should load the entire UTXO set into memory or some sort of SSD cache during the initialization...